# Failed tests are showing as pass in testng output

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have two different testng tests 1. Login 2. Date Picker . what i am doing here, in date picker i had given a past date, so i get a alert message as "Date cannot be past. In testng output i am getting the alert message, but why my result is showing as passedike 1.Book travel- passed 2. Date picker- passed. I want the date picker to be showed as failed in testng output. Some one please reframe this code. I am new to testng. TIA

Please reframe this code.I have two different testng tests 1. Login 2. Date Picker . what i am doing here, in date picker i had given a past date, so i get a alert message as "Date cannot be past. In testng output i am getting the alert message, but why my result is showing as passedike 1.Book travel- passed 2. Date picker- passed. I want the date picker to be show as failed in testng output. Some one please reframe this code. I am new to testng. TIA

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class travelapp {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://Siva//Selenium//chromedriver//chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();        
    }

    @Test
    public void Logintravel() {
        driver.get("https://testsite.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtEmployeeId']")).sendKeys("abcd");    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnSubmit']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_mnuTraveln0']/table/tbody/tr/td/a")).click();
        WebElement radioBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_chkCostCenter']"));
        radioBtn.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);      
   }

   @Test(priority=1)
   public void Datepicker() {                     
       //Travel from date
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_txtTrStartDate']")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_txtTrStartDate_CalendarExtender_day_0_1']")).click();
       Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
       String alertMessage = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
       System.out.println(alertMessage);
  }
 }
```

Please reframe this code.. I have two different testng tests 1. Login 2. Date Picker . what i am doing here, in date picker i had given a past date, so i get a alert message as "Date cannot be past. In testng output i am getting the alert message, but why my result is showing as passedike 1.Book travel- passed 2. Date picker- passed. I want the date picker to be show as failed in testng output. Some one please reframe this code. I am new to testng.

Answer (score 2):

TestNG doesn't care what is the content of the alert, if there weren't any exceptions the test will pass.

You need to [assert](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html) it with other message which shows success. For example

```
String alertMessage = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
Assert.assertEquals(alertMessage, "Data passed successfully");
```

Comment: If i remove the  @Test(priority=1) ,  i am getting no such element exception for  public void Datepicker()  why it is happening.(Please go through the code)..One more question, if there were no exception testng shows as pass, but it is possible to code in testng to mark as failed in output, if we are giving invalid datas. any ideas, with example.Pop up message will come for the previous date, and i wont gate any alert for current dates..Just i need to record the pop up and i want to mark it as failed some how in testng.. Is is possible? any other ways? TIA .

Comment: @Siva If the tests depends on each other changing the order will cause some of them to fail due to missing data. TestNG can detect only exceptions, if there aren't any the test will pass.

Comment: Thanks @Guy.  How can i show this as failed. I understand testng cant do. Any other way. I am getting the below output if i run the code--> .                                 
 Date cannot be in the past... 
PASSED: Logintravel
PASSED: Datepicker

Comment: @Siva This is in my answer, you need to assert the content of the message. If you don't want to use equality click on the link (the underlined "assert"), there are many more options there.

Comment: Thanks @Guy. Now i got a assert message as java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Data passed successfully] but found [Date cannot be in the past.]. Done.... Is this the way bro? done ?

Comment: @Siva Yes. Just replace my message with rhe actual one.